# Reading numbers from command line in c

Tags: c, command-line, integer

Assuming I have a variable:

```
char variableName[256];
```

How can i store input from the command line if i'm given a list of numbers like `10 11 12` .. etc. I'm using

```
fgets(variableName, sizeof(variableName), stdin)
```

and its turning it directly into (`1,0,1,1,` etc) as opposed to the converting between the spaces to (`10, 11, 12,` etc).

Should I perhaps use `scanf`, and store based of white space; Just unsure of the syntax/what is common?

Thanks guys!

Comment: `fgets` doesn't delete whitespace. Can you give some example code and your input?

Comment: "*...  its turning it directly into (1,0,1,1, etc) ...*" please elaborate on this. It's only 1s and 0s? It replaces spaces by commas?

Comment: hey alk! so if i input 30, 4, 10 the char variableName[256]; stores it as (3, 0, 4, 1, 0) so it stores not just 1, and 0s. What im trying to make it store as is (30, 4, 10). Thanks!

Comment: Show us how you call your program “from the command line”.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to call fgets or any other function because arguments passed to program are in argv[] array. You can acces them directly just with

```
int i = atoi( argv[1]);
```

but better you should use `sscanf` which provides error checking:

```
if ( sscanf ( argv[1], "%d", &i) != 1) { printf ( "error - not an integer"); }
```

or `strtol()` which prevents under/overflow:

```
char *endptr, *str;
str = argv[1];
long val = strtol( str, &endptr, 10);
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Comment: This was also what I suspected what OP means, but how she receives "1,0,1,1 etc" (whatever this is) from `stdin` then?

Comment: @mafso OP is misleadingly trying to use stdin when all he needs to get command line params is to use argv[]

Comment: Both `atoi()` and `sscanf("%d")` have undefined behaviour for overflow. Use `strtol()`.

Comment: @DOWNVOTER may I ask you please why you have downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

if you know how many numbers will be inputed then use `sscanf` after using `fgets` or use `scanf` directly (not recommended)

```
  int var[NO_OF_INPUTS];
  fgets(variableName , sizeof variableName , stdin);
  sscanf(variableName , "%d %d %d ... %d" , &var[0] , &var[1] , ... , &var[NO_OF_INPUTS - 1]);
```

if you don't know the number of inputs then you can make a function that counts how many numbers were entered by counting the number of whitespace after `fgets` then maybe use `strtok` to jump between whitespace and `strtol` to convert that into a number

Comment: im using this and just getting a core dump; Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: which one , `strtok` or `sscanf` ?

Comment: oh yes I forgot `&` dumb mistake , try now

Comment: make sure you remove the `\n` from the end of  `variableName` after using `fgets`

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting values from command line then you can simply do the job by using `argc`, `argv` and `strtol`. No need to create new variables!

`argc` contains the number of command line argument passed to your program.

`argv` is the array of arguments.

I hope this code will help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char *p;
    long int li_arr[argc];
    if (argc==1)
    {
        puts("No arguments provided");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        li_arr[i] = strtol(argv[i],&p,10);
        printf("%ld\n",li_arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```